# How to send array of arrays in Query string parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, rest, query-string

I need to send array of arrays by GET api to server. 
By this I get array of 2 objs.

> someurl?{"select":["floor", "shop"}

I need something like this:

```
floor, 
shop:
{ brand }
```

I tried this structure. but it doesn't work

> someurl?{"select":["floor", {"shop":["brand"]}]}

Comment: weird it is not in a parameter and you should be using encodeURIComponent

Comment: @epascarello can you provide example. pls?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
var my_obj={"select":["floor", "shop"]};
var str = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(my_obj));
console.log(str);
var dec_obj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(str));
console.log(dec_obj);
```